# How to allow adding context in url parameters and get the data in model/view?

Tags: url, odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

Odoo normally allows accessing views via urls by specifying necessary properties for it. For example, `{host}/web#id=23&action=985&model=product.template&view_type=form&cids=1&menu_id=688` will redirect the user to product page in my server.

Here comes the point. I created a new tree view with a new model. I would like to access this tree view by url while adding some contexts to it, so that I can use it in the model/views.

How to achieve such task?

I have already tried

1. Adding `&context={'my_context':'123'}` right after its url. The part gets removed upon loading the view.
2. I don't know what `cids` is, but I tried putting some data in there, and it sticks there. However, I don't know how to use it. It most likely exists for other reasons, not my case. So, I don't want to use it.

Comment: cids are the company ids for multi company feature

Comment: if you want to use URLs for opening special views you could create actions which are using this views directly. The action ID can be set in URL parameter `action`.

Comment: the same can be done by using a menu. Which is using actions, so in the end actions should do the trick. And even client actions (ir.actions.client) could do the trick, because you can do much much more with them.

Comment: @CZoellner How do I send context to the `action` in the URL? The data in context is dynamic.

Comment: Hmm, it's also possible to create URL actions, which you could use to open a route (controller) which could use parameters. But i never tried that so i don't have example code.